# Pidgin and Facebook two-factor authentication

Tags: pidgin, facebook, facebook-chat

Since I enabled two-factor authentication on Facebook:

> **Login Approvals**
>
> When an unrecognized computer or device tries to access my account:
> Require me to enter a security code sent to my phone

*pidgin-facebookchat* (the Facebook Chat plugin for Pidgin) has stopped working. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved by miracle!

1. log from pidgin with your first password
2. when you receive the message, log again but using the verification code

Comment: I think this answer is now outdated. See current correct answer below.

Answer (score 13):

Add an app password:[here](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=per_app_passwords&view)

This will generate a separate password you can give to pidgin that will not require 2-factor auth.